# How to display a line of buttons as a grid instead

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to align buttons in div to get the effect in the photo below, all I want to have all at center of page, small circles should be in separate div because by default they are invisible so it's easier to change parameter of div than four buttons. Now I have stopped at this point:
[image: What I have]

below is what I want:
[image: What I want]

```css
 .guzik {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
}
.guzik1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color:white;
    padding: 0 0px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <input name="1" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+1" />
      <input name="2" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+2" />
      <input name="3" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+3" />
      <input name="4" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+4" />
      <input name="Color1" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+1" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
      <input name="Color2" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+2" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
      <input name="Color3" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+3" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
      <input name="Color4" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+4" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and a `<br>` element:

```css
.set {
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  margin-left: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 { color: grey }

.smallpegs {
  padding-top: 15px
}

.bigpegs {}

.guzik {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

.guzik1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 0px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Mastermind</h1>
    <h3>Orgadnij kod</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <div class="smallpegs">
      <input name="1" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+1" />
      <input name="2" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+2" /><br/>
      <input name="3" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+3" />
      <input name="4" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+4" />
    </div>
    <div class="bigpegs">
      <input name="Color1" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+1" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
      <input name="Color2" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+2" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
      <input name="Color3" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+3" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
      <input name="Color4" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+4" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <div class="smallpegs">
      <input name="1" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+1" />
      <input name="2" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+2" /><br/>
      <input name="3" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+3" />
      <input name="4" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+4" />
    </div>
    <div class="bigpegs">
      <input name="Color1" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+1" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
      <input name="Color2" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+2" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
      <input name="Color3" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+3" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
      <input name="Color4" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+4" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know it could be so simple, thanks. I see that text align:center stops working, instead I used justify-content:center, the "big" buttons are not perfectly centered under the word "mastermind" slightly shifted to the right probably because of the small buttons in the line, can it be fixed somehow? EDIT : Ok I resolved this by .big {
   padding-right: 50px;
}

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example on how you could achieve the desired behavior using css grid.

The fraction unit allows you to split your grid into parts.
For more explanation regarding the grid I refer to the following [website](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Edited and added the title / control section:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: .25fr .25fr .25fr .25fr;
}
.title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.title h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.title p {
  font-family: arial;
}
.line {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: .2fr .8fr;
}
.squared {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: .5fr .5fr;
  grid-template-columns: .5fr .5fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
.aligned {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: .25fr .25fr .25fr .25fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;
}
.circle {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.controls input[type="button"] {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px/5px;
  font-family: arial;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>MasterMind</h1>
    <p>Ogadnij Kod</p>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="squared">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="aligned">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="squared">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="aligned">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="button" value="Sprawdz kolory">
  </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know of this is helpful for you.

Comment: Now add the Mastermide centered above the big circles

Comment: @mplungjan: Did it. :p

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the grid to achieve 4 small boxes in 1 big box and then 4 in another row. I'm a beginner myself but I think this solution below kinda solves the task at hand.

```css
.gridbox {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 400px;
}

.smoolgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.smoolgrid button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: fit-content;
}

.gridbox button {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridbox">
  <div class="smoolgrid">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>4</button>
  </div>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
</div>

<div class="gridbox">
  <div class="smoolgrid">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>4</button>
  </div>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is what you are after but this puts 4 small boxes in 1 of the 5 big grid slots could make it more identical to your example if you change the size and max width etc

```css
#gridbox {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#smoolgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gridbox">
  <div id="smoolgrid">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>4</button>
  </div>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your circles here are squeezed either vertically or horizontally, to a severe extent (to the point where they are not circles anymore).

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this easily with bootstrap

```css
.guzik {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 2px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

.guzik1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 0px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <input name="Color1" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+1" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
    <input name="Color2" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+2" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
    <input name="Color3" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+3" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
    <input name="Color4" type="button" class="guzik" id="0+4" onclick="changeColor1(id)" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <input name="1" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+1" />
    <input name="2" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+2" />
    <input name="3" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+3" />
    <input name="4" type="button" class="guzik1" id="k 0+4" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sprawdz kolory</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you run this?

Comment: yes. its working fine for me

Comment: It does not look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RA2m.png - and why use bootstrap when you can just use flex?

Comment: bootstrap is very easy to use compared to custom css.

Comment: Not for this. Just use grid or flex

Comment: This does not put the circles in a grid; they're still in a single row.